# factoring a differential quotient

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, factoring

The original function is $$ (y^2+yx)dx+x^2dy = 0 $$

I've arrived at $$\frac{dx}{x} + \frac{du}{u(u+2)} = 0 $$

The text book carries on to factor as such, but I don't understand how they justify it:
$$\frac{dx}{x}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{u}-\frac{1}{u+2}\right)du=0
  $$

Any clues how they got that $1/2$? Why'd they stick a minus sign between two fractions that were previously multiplied by each other?

Comment: Partial fractions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a decomposition by partial fractions. Note that

$$\frac{1}{u} - \frac{1}{u + 2} = \frac{(u + 2) - u}{u(u + 2)} = 2 \frac{1}{u(u + 2)}$$